# PowerShell, way to reload a script? (Like close and start script?)

Tags: winforms, powershell

I have added a simple autoupdater function to my PowerShell script, so that when I make a change and upload it to my website, it get's automatically downloaded to the user computer and replaces the .ps1 file - and voila the user has the newest version.

Though, the user has to close the PS script and start it again before the runs with the newest file.

Is there a function that I can implement that restarts the PS script? Just like when the user closes and reopens the PS script?

Best regards

Comment: Since this is tagged winforms, do you mean to say that you wish for your script to be reran once the user closes the GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your exact needs the Import-Module cmdlet should solve the problem.  If it were me, I'd make a static "loader" script that just does whatever update logic you have, and then imports the script.  Let me know if you have any further specific questions on methodology.